# How can I add points to the diagram on the winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, math, mschart

I solve a problem of fuzzy modeling.

I need to build a chart on the original data. From a .txt file, I read the values.

The chart is built like this:

the minimum value from the list is + = the step where the step is (the maximum value minus the minimum) / 2/2, because I have 5 graphs.

That is, I have `3, 3.101, 3.12, 3.15, 3.2, 3.4, 3.45`

If we said that we want use 5 elements, then 3.2 is the maximum point. I build on one point: the minimum value + = step! = Maximum.
And how now to reflect the points that are from the array ?

(I used google translate.)

```
List<double> lsDouble;
step = ((lsDouble[kount - 1] - lsDouble[0]) / 2) /2;
double sumX;

for(int i=0; i<kount;i++)
    {
        sumX = lsDouble[0];
        chart1.Series[i].BorderWidth = 6;
        for (int j = 0; j<kount;j++)
        {
           if (i == j)  valY = 1;
           else valY = 0;

           chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(sumX, valY);
           sumX += step;
        }
    }
```

I have:

[image]

I need to get:

[image: points on this chart with vertical lines]

Code:

```
switch (kount)
                {
                    case 2:
                        step = (lsDouble[kount - 1] - lsDouble[0]);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        step = (lsDouble[kount - 1] - lsDouble[0]) / 2;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        step = ((lsDouble[kount - 1] - lsDouble[0]) / 2) /2;
                        break;

                }


                double sumX;

                for(int i=0; i<kount;i++)
                {
                    sumX = lsDouble[0];
                    chart1.Series[i].BorderWidth = 6;
                    for (int j = 0; j<kount;j++)
                    {
                        if (i == j)
                            valY = 1;
                        else valY = 0;

                        chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(sumX, valY);
                        sumX += step;
                        //if(sumX==lsDouble[kount-1])
                        //    chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(sumX, valY);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I'm afraid you need to explain more clearly what you want. Let's start with: How many Series do you want? Really 7? Or 5, as you wrote? Next: What does a line of data look like? Is that one line: _3, 3.101, 3.12, 3.15, 3.2, 3.4, 3.45_ ? These are indeed 7 values.. Next: What exactly is the difference between the two images? Color? The dotted lines? The vertical connections? How many series are in the 2nd image? How would the 2nd image  look with colored series?

Comment: @TaW, In the 7-value file, this is true, but the user uses the combo to determine how many values from 7, to choice 2, 3, and 5. So I described an example for 5 values.
About txt file, yes, this is one line, but I have already output this data to the code in the list.
I built the color image myself, it's true, but it does not have enough values from the list. In the second image (black and white) there are X values that have two values for Y. I need to do also, I will not know how to add points, knowing X and display on the color chart. The second chart has 5 series.

Comment: Ok. Sounds like the user can determine how many of the values in  aline are to be displayed, 2, 3, 5 or maybe 7, right? So the number of series is dynamic. Now to the data: Are the numbers in the file the x- or the y-values? They do look like the x-values, with y only having 0 or 1. Right? If so, how is it determined? It says `if (i == j)`. Can you explan the logic just a little?

Comment: @TaW, Briefly speaking, the problem is to find the values of Y from the known X from the list. And the mapping of these points with respect to x and y

Comment: Um, that was a bit too briefly. Did I get things right? And: Can you post a few (5-10, or whatever led to the chart output) lines of your data? Also: There is no problem in a Line (or Point) chart with having points at the same x and even x&y values.

Comment: @TaW, In the file, the values of X.
The logic is that the area from the minimum to the maximum is divided into parts. These are already fuzzy sets - mathematics.
But I know that this is so, that is, my color chart is correctly drawn, but this is only part of the assignment.

Comment: The logic is as follows:

graph 1, a point with respect to x = 3, y = 1

graph 1, point in x + = step (3 + step), y = 0

.................................................. ....................
graph 1, the point with respect to x = the maximum value, y = 0
graph 2, a point with respect to x = 3, y = 0
graph 2, a point with respect to x + = step, y = 1
..............................................

graph 2, the point with respect to x = the maximum value, y = 0

Comment: @TaW, little did not understand about linear and point charts. I would be grateful if you could explain.

Comment: There are various ChartTyles, like Pie, Column, Bar. Line and Point are two types that will allow adding DataPoints at the same x/y spots and display them like a graph in geometry. Just a note that basically this will work, if you add enough points.

Comment: @TaW, okay, i understand about ChartTypes. You undestanted the entity of my quesiton?))

Comment: No, I'm afraid not, I'm not into the problem domain (fuzzy logic) at all. But I do know a lot about charts, so if I know the result I usually can get it. Often it helps to insert a step that prepares the data before pumping them into the chart.. Simply posting a par of the text file might help, too.

Comment: Looks russian to me. There is a [Russian SO site!](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjv9cekht_aAhVRlxQKHatjCUsQFjAAegQIABAr&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.stackoverflow.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw3wDFRjQ_U9Mrt0xyxgJM-d)

Comment: @TaW, Sorry. I forgot translate) I was able to solve, like, this problem in the field of mathematics. Maybe you know how to add points with x, y to the chart?
I used the equation of a straight line for two points. Received a system of equations.
1x + 0.05y-3.05 = 0
-1x + 0.05y + 3 = 0
For point 3.025 on these equations, I have two Y points, how do I now add them with vertical lines down, as in the black and white image?

Comment: You simply add __two__ points, same x-values and different y-values. This should work. (((Unless your Series has XValuesAreIndexed = true, which must be false, the default)))